# PHP form to MySQL and save as template twist

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've created a PHP form whereas the user selects from a menu one of 4 form, enters the appropriate data, then on submittal the data is saved to a MySQL database and displayed in a table list.

The form is part of a backend CRM record keeping web application used to create bids.

I've been requested to add a feature and can't figure out the best way to handle it.

In addition to the submit button already live I need to add essentially a Submit and Save as new template button.  This should do the same thing, saving to the database and adding it to the table but should also present itself as a new template pre filled with the data so if the user likes the way they composed the bid they can choose to save it and can use the input they previously entered as a template for writing future bids.

The same affect as essentially creating a duplicate record.

I'm walking into this as primarily a JavaScript front end developer, taking over on a very poorly constructed project written primarily in PHP by the previous developer.  I'd really appreciate any help as I'm pretty much lost at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to help without the code. but if I understand you correctly you need to insert the data to two tables right?

Comment: Yes I believe so.  The code is a mess but I'll share it tomorrow if it would be enlightening